# HTTP Error 500.23 after adding dotless to my local website

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config, dotless

Hi I'm trying to run [dotless](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) on my local .net4 web site

**My web config looks like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="dotless" type="dotless.Core.configuration.DotlessConfigurationSectionHandler, dotless.Core" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  <httpHandlers><add path="*.less" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler, dotless.Core" /></httpHandlers></system.web>
<dotless minifyCss="false" cache="true" web="false" />

    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="dotless" path="*.less" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler,dotless.Core" resourceType="File" preCondition="" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Here is the error I get**

```
HTTP Error 500.23 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.
Most likely causes:

    This application defines configuration in the system.web/httpHandlers section.
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 29):

adding  `<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>` worked

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="dotless" type="dotless.Core.configuration.DotlessConfigurationSectionHandler, dotless.Core" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*.less" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler, dotless.Core" />
  </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
<dotless minifyCss="false" cache="true" web="false" />

    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <handlers>
            <add name="dotless" path="*.less" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler,dotless.Core" resourceType="File" preCondition="" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This fixed my issue for an ancient project that I needed to run!  Thanks +1.

Answer (score 13):

`<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>` [tells IIS to ignore configuration issues](http://forums.iis.net/t/1150266.aspx). One such issue seems to be the fact that dotless automatically adds a handler to `system.web` and `system.webServer`. The former section is used by the classic application pool mode, whereas the latter by the new integrated application pool mode. Since I am using the integrated mode, removing the handler in system.web helped just as well.

Comment: Thanks!. I just deleted the httpHandler section from system.web section and everything ok.

Comment: This should be the answer as it actually addresses the root problem rather than putting a bandaid over it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add     `<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>` to my webserver section and I also had to move the configSections to be the first element in my Configuration.

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
<section name="dotless" type="dotless.Core.configuration.DotlessConfigurationSectionHandler, dotless.Core" />
```

Answer (score -1):

We will add a small piece of code into web.config file.  open web.config from your IIS root or change the setting in Visual Studio web.config and publish again.

```
  <system.webServer>
            <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
          </system.webServer>
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of prior answer