# How to set ASP.NET MVC 5 to use dotless/LESS

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, less, dotless

Can someone tell me how to use dotless/LESS with MVC 5?

I tried to install dotless from NuGet using:

```
install-packege dotless
```

But I get this error when I run my project:

> An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.
>   **Most likely causes:**
>   This application defines configuration in the system.web/httpHandlers section.

Comment: You'll need to provide more details. Which NuGet package are you trying to use? Do you want to use the built-in Bundler or are you using a different workflow? Show us what you have tried and the errors are you getting.

Comment: i was edit my question, please see my error

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17809889/2030565) will get rid of your HTTP 500.23 error. There is also further discussion on this configuration [here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1161020.aspx?HTTP+Error+500+23+How+do+i+solve+this+).

Comment: Do you use twitter bootstrap? Dotless had an issue when it can't parse bootstrap ie styles.

Comment: no i don't. i just try dotless, thanks for your advice Roman :)

Answer (score 0):

`system.web/httpHandlers` is used for IIS 6, so if this is not your option (for example you use IIS 7+) just remove `httpHandlers` section from `web.config`

Or instead of removing `httpHandlers` just add `validateIntegratedModeConfiguration` option into `system.webServer` section.

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  ...
```

These links can be useful on how to use dotless:

http://www.brendanforster.com/blog/yet-another-implement-less-in-aspnetmvc-post.html

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification

[Dotless - Can't reference less variable in separate file with MVC Bundling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403346/dotless-cant-reference-less-variable-in-separate-file-with-mvc-bundling)